# Angular6 get all filenames from folder

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular5, angular6

I'm trying to make a simple Picture Gallery and I want to place all the pictures inside a Folder (./assets/).

Now I created a PictureService which should load all Pictures (well his names to be precise) in an Array so that I can iterate over the array and display them.

But how do I grep the FileNames? I did something similar with nodejs and liquid once where I simply called a bash job to return the names to me but that doesn't seem clean nor possible here.

I really want to hold it clean and simple and don't want to build an extra API for this, to be honest.

And I don't want to manual input all these filenames into a JSON or the array either...

Is there any smart way of doing it?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think your image response api should be in json like this-
`{ name: 'image1-name', path: 'image1-url' }, {name: 'image2-name', path:'image2-url' }` and try to use observable and subscribe for consuming this json api.

Comment: and how do you feed the json? I mean when the folder content changes, the JSON has to change as well.